# inner join with two tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have two tables equipment and equipmenthistory.

**equipment** contains serialNum and status column and serialNum is primary key of that table.

**equipmenthistory** contains id, serialNum and status.. id is primary key of that table.

equipmenthistory table contain multiple rows with same serialNum

```
i need equipment.serialNum , equipment.status and list of equipmenthistory where serialNum  is same
```

Please help me to solve it. i wana do it with inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two options provide the same results. The first is shorthand for the second option.

**Option 1**

```
Select equipment.serialNum, equipment.status, equipmenthistory.id, equipmenthistory.serialNum,  equipmenthistory.status
From equipment
Inner Join  equipmenthistory using(serialNum)
```

**Option 2**

```
Select equipment.serialNum, equipment.status, equipmenthistory.id, equipmenthistory.serialNum,  equipmenthistory.status
From equipment
Inner Join  equipmenthistory 
On equipment.serialNum = equipmenthistory.serialNum
```